# How To Write For Loop Data Into a CSV file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv, ebay-api

I'm building a BOT that can scrape prices of products of off ebay and write all the info into a csv file. But I'm having trouble when it inputs the information into the csv file as it's using a for loop. How do I write all the for loop data into the csv file. The code only writes the last product's info because of the for loop.

```
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'}

searchterm = "Laptops"
url = f'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw={searchterm}&_sacat=0&LH_PrefLoc=1&LH_Auction=1&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1'

response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')

for item in soup.select('.s-item'):
    print(len(soup.select('.s-item')))
    try:
        print(item.select('.s-item__title')[0].get_text())
        print(item.select('.s-item__subtitle')[0].get_text())
        print(item.select('.s-item__price')[0].get_text())
        print(item.select('.s-item__location')[0].get_text())
        print(item.select('.s-item__shipping')[0].get_text())
        print("\n\n\n----------------------------------------------")
        with open('Products.csv', mode='w') as file_in:
            writers = csv.writer(writers)
            employee_writer.writerow(['Product', 'Price'])
            employee_writer.writerow(['', ''])
            employee_writer.writerow([item.select('.s-item__title')[0].get_text(),item.select('.s-item__price')[0].get_text()])
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR!")
```

I want the tables to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibmkx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure the code so that you're opening the file outside of the loop:

```
with open('Products.csv', mode='w') as file_in:
    writers = csv.writer(writers)
    for item in soup.select('.s-item'):
        # etc...
```

What's happening is that each iteration of the loop, you're re-opening the file, and with `mode='w'` you're overwriting the file contents.